# Сравнение двух пачек файлов

Tags: windows, файлы, bat, diff

Есть два папки с одинаковыми файлами (по именам), нужно проверить, правда ли, что соответствующие файлы совпадают.

Файлы являются .png картинками. Подойдёт любой способ, как попиксельное сравнение, так и через какие-нибудь хеш-суммы.

Как это эффективнее всего сделать средствами OS Windows ? Может есть какие-нибудь утилиты для подобного, или можно небольшой батник написать?

Comment: Тотал-коммандером сделать хеши к одной папке и проверить на другой

Comment: WinDiff - сравнивает прямо папками

Comment: Тесты на эффективность в сравнении с "Far Manager" не проводил, но при малых объемах хватало встроенной консольной утилиты сравнения. Пример использования для бинарных файлов: **"fc c:\dir1\* c:\dir2\* /b"**. Рекурсивно каталоги не обрабатывает.

Comment: Попробовал сделать с fc: fc e:\dir1* e:\dir2* /b , выдало ошибку: FC: cannot open E:\DIR1* - No such file or folder, что ему не нравится? папки на диске есть

Comment: https://github.com/ermig1979/AntiDupl

Comment: форматирование съело синтаксис моего предыдущего коммента: "fc c:\dir1\\* c:\dir2\\* /b"